# Checking classList with contains if a class exists before add or remove?

Tags: javascript

A colleague of mine insists that it is important to check first if a class exists on an element before adding or removing it.

Therefore he has lot of constructs in his code like this:

```
if (element.classList.contains('info')) {
    element.classList.remove('info');
}

if (!element.classList.contains('hint')) {
    element.classList.add('hint');
}
```

I personally guess that nothing would happen if one leaves the check with .contains( ) out.

Shall mean:

If the class isn't there nothing is removed. The statement is just meaningless.

If the class is already there then nothing is added.

Is my colleague right with his insisting on the check because not checking could result in some trouble?

Or can I forget about that checking?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Explicitly checking is pointless. It is a waste of time and bloats your code.

Those checks are effectively built-in to the add and remove class methods.

If you try to add a class that the element is already a member of, then `classList.add` will ignore it.

If you try to remove a class that the element isn't a member of, then `classList.remove` will do nothing.

Comment: I agree, and even if it had a use, which it hasn't, one should consider putting this "checking" code into some sort of function, if only for the sake of briefness in the code.

Comment: @Quentin " ... and bloats your code." Yeah, exactly. That's what I thought when I saw it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note: using `classList.remove` on a class that does not exist on a element fires an error in Internet Explorer 10. If you're willing to support this browser, take care - `classList.add` has no problem.

Answer (score 6):

Both the ways are correct there is no sense that it is important but in some cases you may need to use `.contains()` totally depends on you situation.

But globally its not important you can directly remove the class. If class exists then code will work otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

Use .className to check whether the given className is present or not.

```
if (element.className == 'info') {
    element.classList.remove('info');
}
if (element.className == 'hint') {
    element.classList.add('hint');
}
```

This code has worked for me perfectly.

Comment: It will not work if the element has multiple class ? Also StackOverflow is a Q&A, not a forum. So this will not stay secret

Comment: If an element only has one class at a time, you can change it by simply setting `element.className`  to the new class name. You can also remove the only class of an element by setting its `className` property to the empty string. However adding `hint` to an element which already has `hint` as its class doesn't do anything. This isn't an answer to the question asked.